# How to check where a function is referenced from

Tags: c++, c, gcc, freertos, bare-metal

In a bare metal C/C++ project, I use [gcc-arm-embedded](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded) (currently the most recent [4.9-2015-q2](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/4.9/4.9-2015-q2-update)).

For some reasons, I have to avoid using some functions, like some of stdio et cetera (don't want to use retargeting or semihosting).

Further, I use FreeRtos with heap_4.c and had e.g. `malloc()` redirected directly to `pvPortMalloc()` like this:

```
void* malloc(size_t s) {
    return pvPortMalloc(s);
}
```

Therefore, I don't want to have any parts of the toolchain's heap management code within my binary.

Now, there are some situations, as were a developer of my team means to use e.g. `printf()` which indirectly references `_malloc_r()` (and some more) and it's actually quite hard to find out where it's referenced from and so where to fix.

(The use `printf()` is just an example here. In my project, I have custom implementation of printf() which prints directly to uart without using stdio. But there are other cases, e.g. type info demangeling, …)

Currently, I have the situation that my project (which consists of about 200 c and c++ source files) compiles well without referencing `_malloc_r()` in any way - as long as I build with [gcc 4.8](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/4.8/4.8-2014-q3-update).

But when building with [gcc 4.9](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/4.9/4.9-2015-q2-update), I see unwanted references to `_malloc_r` and some more.

Might there be command line tool to analyze my elf file for finding out where specific functions are referenced from?

Edit 2015-07-20:

- Finally, I'd solved my underlying problem, that I need to build my whole project with [gcc 4.9](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/4.9/4.9-2015-q2-update) without having references to `_malloc_r` inside of my code.
- Some of the references I'd found by applying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31091776/2880699).
- Further I find out, that there is a `__gnu_cxx::__snprintf_lite()` which references the full blown of `iostream` which I don't want in my code. This `__gnu_cxx::__snprintf_lite()` is used by some exceptions of the `gcc` `stl` implementation (e.g. referenced by `__throw_out_of_range_fmt()`). (Yep, my code uses `std::map`). My way to get rid of `iostream` was to simply provide my own `__gnu_cxx::__snprintf_lite()` like this (having my own small footprint `vsnprintf`):

  ```
  namespace __gnu_cxx {
      int __snprintf_lite(char* buf, size_t bufsize, const char* fmt, va_list ap) {
          return vsnprintf(buf, bufsize, fmt, ap);
      }
  }
  ```

  This can be checked by viewing the gcc-4.9 library sources (e.g. `src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/snprintf_lite.cc`).

Comment: Perhaps the linker can tell you, if you can prevent inclusion of a definition of the relevant function(s).

Comment: Unfortulately, I don't know the names of all functions which could directly or indirectly results in references of e.g. `_malloc_r`.

Comment: You could use `objdump -d` to disassemble all executable sections and redirect the output to a file and search for `_malloc_r` in it with a text editor.

Comment: Take a look to Hooks-for-Malloc http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html

Comment: LD_PRELOAD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948448/gcc-how-to-block-system-calls-within-a-program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example for finding out the references to `_exit` in a statically compiled program:

```
/* hello.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    write(1, "Hello\n", 6);
    _exit(0);
}
```

Compile it:

```
$ gcc hello.c -static -g
```

Find out the address of `_exit`:

```
$ nm a.out | grep " _exit"
000000000040f760 T _exit
```

Disassemble with `objdump -d -j .text`, `grep` for the address of `_exit`, `cut` the address out of the line and pipe it to `addr2line`:

```
$ objdump -d -j .text a.out | grep 40f760 | cut -c 1-8 | addr2line -e a.out -f
oom
dl-tls.o:?
main
/home/m/hello.c:8
__run_exit_handlers
??:?
??
??:0
_Exit
??:?
_dl_non_dynamic_init
??:?
abort
??:?
do_lookup_x
dl-lookup.o:?
_dl_relocate_object
??:?
_dl_signal_error
??:?
dl_open_worker
dl-open.o:?
_dl_close_worker.part.0
dl-close.o:?
_dl_start_profile
??:?
```

The result is:

Functions `oom`, `main`, `__run_exit_handlers`, ... do reference the function `_exit`.

Comment: I think, this leads to the right direction. Could you tell the reason of the `oom` argument of `addr2line`?

Comment: @Joe `oom` is part of the output of `addr2line`. It is a `static` [function](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/elf/dl-tls.c) (out of  memory) in the dl library which calls `_exit`.

Comment: Well, using this approch, I find out that `_malloc_r` is referenced by `__ssprint_r` and `__submore`; `__ssprint_r` itself is referenced by something named `St`?! `__submore` is referenced by `_sungetc_r` which also referenced by `St`. At this point, I stuck on trying to follow the referencing chain up to my own code.

Comment: Following the address of that `St` by manually checking the `objdump` output, I see that it is referenced by `__ssvfscanf_r` which is referenced by `sscanf` which is referenced by `_ZSt14__convert_to_vIeEvPKcRT_RSt12_Ios_IostateRKPi` (`void std::__convert_to_v<long double>(char const*, long double&, std::_Ios_Iostate&, int* const&)`) which leads me to some iostream related template stuff.

Comment: After researching my code for a while, I find out that there are some different indirect refences to `_malloc_r` (in my concrete case). Some of them I'd found using this approach (e.g. `localtime()` and `mktime()` are referencing `_malloc_r` indirectly (via `mktime` → `_tzset_unlocked` → `_tzset_unlocked_r` → `_malloc_r`) when building with gcc-arm 4.9); another hit, I'd described within my question

Answer (score 2):

Peraphs using a custom malloc.h where you can undef or redefine _malloc_r

Something similar to:

```
extern _PTR malloc _PARAMS ((size_t));
#ifdef __CYGWIN__
#undef _malloc_r
#define _malloc_r(r, s) malloc (s)
#else
extern _PTR _malloc_r _PARAMS ((struct _reent *, size_t));
#endif
```

Take a look to [Hooks-for-Malloc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html) too

> The GNU C Library lets you modify the behavior of malloc, realloc, and
>   free by specifying appropriate hook functions. You can use these hooks
>   to help you debug programs that use dynamic memory allocation, for
>   example.
>
> The hook variables are declared in malloc.h.

Another hint is using LD_PRELOAD [What is the LD_PRELOAD trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick)

Comment: Yep, IMHO there is no way for `LD_PRELOAD` on bare metal.

Comment: About malloc hooks: `_malloc_c()` is just an example. I'd somtimes also observed unwanted references to e.g. `_write()` or some other (not stdio related) unwanted functions.

Comment: `-flto` won't help because the unwanted `_malloc_r()` is really referenced (indirectly e.g. via `sprintf` or something else) and I have to find the guilty code location in my sources.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, whether I understood you correctly, but it seems you want to avoid using some specific functions in your project. How about simply poisoning the function identifiers?

This code fails to compile (intentionally) for `printf`:

```
#define printf FORBIDDEN

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("Test");
}
```

with the following error:

```
Untitled.cpp:11:3: error: no matching function for call to 'FORBIDDEN'
  printf("Test");
  ^~~~~~
Untitled.cpp:3:16: note: expanded from macro 'printf'
#define printf FORBIDDEN
               ^~~~~~~~~
```

So the order of declaration and redefinition does not matter. You do not need to know all functions that call forbidden functions:

```
#define printf FORBIDDEN

// this in included file:
void otherfunc() {
  printf("I fail.");
}
// eof included file

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  otherfunc();
}
```

Comment: This approch results in that I have to maintain a blacklist of all forbidden functions. Further, it poisens all `printf` keywords in code, even such a possible allowed `OutStream::printf` implementation.